# fixed navigation bar not only with position:fixed

Tags: css, position, fixed

Is it possible to make an HTML Element fixed so it stay at the same position when the user scrolls?

The Problem is: If I use "position:fixed", The Elements loses its relation to the containers and changes the actual position. It pops out of the site wrapper (of course) but I would like it to keep its position and just also keep the position  when scrolled.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the elements **position** to **fixed**, but don't set its **top**, **left**, **bottom** or **right** parameters.

As long as you don't set them, your element will stay on the place where it belongs (relative to the initial parent positioning)

```
.your-element{
    position: relative;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/272zbph1/)

Comment: I use the child theme sample of genesis framework.When I change the position of my nav bar to "position:fixed" it pops out of its position and moves to the left of the page outside of the site wrapper where it was inside before

Comment: Did you check the jsfiddle link I included? You can see that the orange block is keeping its original position no matter what yo do (resize, scroll..), so make sure that your nav bar does not have any "positioning css" applied to it beforehand by the framework itself, as it will only move to the left if "left:0;" is set.

Comment: The framework is confusing for me. I found a positioning related to the nav bar, it says:

 "left: -9999px;
 position: absolute;"

I don't know what's the purpose of this, but when I delete it, the navigation falls completely apart

Comment: If you could provide a link to the site, would be much easier to find out the issue!

Comment: Please add the "width:100%;" to your "nav" element.

Answer (score 0):

With css you can only do this with `position:fixed`. The problem you line out can be mitigates somewhat if you know the height of the element. You can set `margin-top` on an element around the content to offset it from the top.

```
#topbar {
  height: 5em;
}

#content {
  margin-top: 5em;
}
```

```css
#topbar {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:5em;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px red dotted;
}

#content {
  margin-top: 5em;
  padding-top: 5px;
  background: #EEEEFF;
  border: 1px blue dotted;
  height: 500em;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">Something in the topbar</div>
<div id="content">This text is magically displayed under the topbar</div>
```

Comment: Hey Sumurai8 my problem is not the height, actually it stays at the correct height. It moves to the very left of the page, thats the problem

Comment: Unless your page scrolls horizontally *shudders* just play with the `left` css option then.

Comment: I tried this of course but the problem is that the navigation bar still behaves differently when the viewport is changed then. So the Responsiveness isn't clean anymore. I'd really like to stick where it is and behave as it did before just beeing fixed when scrolled.

Comment: Define "responsiveness". From the definition you can learn how to make your fixed navigation bar also responsive.

Comment: I guess youre right. If I put the navbar "left: 10%" for desktop and for smaller viewports on for example "left: 5%" it should be fine, since if I leave it at 10% it is just too far to the right. Ill just have to figure out how that works but it shouldn't be too tough.